# Redis on Docker (Windows) - Custom Config File

Tags: docker, redis

I have a need to use an in-memory caching solution for scaled out application servers.

Redis seems like  the best choice from my research.

I've used Linux before (Ubuntu), but I don't consider myself an expert at all.
So I'm considering just going with a Windows install.

The Windows port isn't official and seems to be abandoned.

I figured this would be a good time to learn all about Docker, as I've heard it grow popular over the past couple of years.

I have got to the point where I can install Docker and run some containers with no issue.

For redis, I can do the following from a command line with no issue:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 redis
```

But this is needed for a production system and I'm just unsure if I am using best practices or how I should configure my config file.  And I also want to make sure I have high availability (master/slave).

Can anyone help me get on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

There's gonna be a performance overhead running Redis in docker for windows as it installs docker on a virtual machine and then runs Redis within that.

Also bear in mind that '-p 6379:6379' will expose redis to the outside network, not just your host machine. Maybe that's what you want, maybe not.

Comment: I thought that docker doesn't run as a VM. It maps the host machine's low level calls to the docker container. Am I wrong?

Comment: On linux that's the case, but it can't on mac/windows so it uses a VM.